# Executing .exe file using node runs only once in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I write some tests using jasmine and protractor i want in the @beforeeach to execute .exe file using require('child_process') and then @aftereach i will restart the browser.
The problem is that the .exe file is executed only once with the first spec.
here is the code in the beforeEach()

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    console.log("before each is called");
    var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

    browser.get('URL'); 
    console.log("fun() start");
    var child = exec('Test.exe', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('executed');
        done();

        process.on('exit', function() {
            child.kill();
            console.log("process is killed");
        });

    });
```

Then i wrote 2 specs and in the aftereach i restart the browser

```
afterEach(function() {
        console.log("close the browser");
        browser.restart();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `done` and `done.fail` methods to exit the async `beforeEach`. You begin to execute `Test.exe` and immediately call done. This could have undesired results since the process could still be executing. I do not believe `process.on('exit'` every gets called. Below might get you started on the right track using event emitters from the child process.

```
beforeEach((done) => {
  const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

  browser.get('URL'); 

  // child is of type ChildProcess
  const child = execFile('Test.exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      done.fail(stderr);
    }
    console.log(stdout);
  });

  // ChildProcess has event emitters and should be used to check if Test.exe
  // is done, has an error, etc.
  // See: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess

  child.on('exit', () => {
    done();
  });
  child.on('error', (err) => {
    done.fail(stderr);
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried your solution.The child process has exited but it run only once.In the second spec it didn't get executed

Comment: Then we need more information about your tests. I would add a small snippet of  your `describe`, `beforeEach`, and `it` blocks.